# Javascript Variable Showing undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, nested, undefined

I have a global javascript array and i am able to call values from it at the beginning of the function but after that, when i alert leaders[i], it shows as undefined:
It appears the problem occurs when there are two ajax calls nested in each other, JS cannot seem to find the values in the array.

JS

```
function getLeaders(bool) {
    var leaders = new Array();
    leaders.push('444');
    leaders.push('111');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'clubID': curClub
        },
        success: function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < leaders.length; i++)
              {
                  alert(leaders[i]); <===== working fine here
                  $.ajax({
                       url: 'someurl',
                       crossDomain: true,
                       type: 'post',
                       data: {
                           'id': leaders[i] <====== works here
                       },
                       success: function(data3) {
                           alert(leaders[i]);      <======= undefined here
                           var json3 = jQuery.parseJSON(data3);
                       }
                });
            }
           }
      });
     };
```

Comment: Of course if makes sense. You variable `i` changes to leaders.length value by the time your second ajax completes. Try to console log your value of i

Comment: Probably this kind of nesting use of a variable is lead by a bad structure of the code

Comment: Hm.. leaders appears to be of length 2 though, and the loop goes until < 2

Comment: yeah it should work fine..

Comment: print out the length of leaders.

Comment: I think I've found a decent solution try surrounding the second ajax call in an immediately invoked function that takes i as a parameter. This will forgo the outside variable and will allow you to pass in the right value of i for each loop. like in the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254098/get-in-a-loop-why-the-function-is-performed-after-incrementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the call is asynchronous the value of i is more than likely leader.length by the time the call returns. So you are probably accessing an index that is out-of bounds.

Comment: i dont think i can do this because i need the leaders[i] in my second ajax call

Comment: It's possible, just not good, as I used as a hopeful disclaimer.

Comment: i printed out i inside the second success, and it was 2, you were right

Comment: is there any way you can give me a more detailed fix to the problem, im very confused as to how to approach this

Comment: I'm fairly new to SO. Is there a way I can send you message?

Comment: one second let me find it

Comment: The only solution I can think is really not the greatest and had me immediately down-voted. I have a jsfiddle for it, but i'd rather avoid the many 'this is bad and you should feel bad' comments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34026/discussion-between-nshah-and-clyde-byrd-iii)